# Validating an EditText

Tags: java, android

I have an `EditText` (et) in my app. I want to be able to limit the character count AND to validate the input.

My input type is a string sequence for example, n = number, a = alpha. If I have say, 10 (max) chars, my input string will be something like...

aannnnnnna

I am having problems making this all work. It seems to be failing on my character count first (I commented the validation out). I am getting a strange problem where my text is doubling up. Here is my code...

```
et.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            if (source.equals("")) {
                return source;
            }
            else {
                String boxInput = source.toString();
                String textFormat = options.getFormattedTextFormat();
                int maxChars = options.getFormattedTextMaxChars();
                if (maxChars > 0 && source.length() > maxChars) {
                    Toast.makeText(OpenForm.this, R.string.maxCharsText + " " + maxChars, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    boxInput = source.toString().substring(0,maxChars - 1);
                    source = boxInput;
                }
                if (!textFormat.isEmpty()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < boxInput.length(); i++) {
                        char c = boxInput.charAt(i);
                        char test = textFormat.charAt(i);

                        if (test == 'n' && !Character.isDigit(c)) {
                            // Testing for a number, but character is not a number
                            Toast.makeText(OpenForm.this, R.string.badNumber + " " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (test == 'a' && Character.isDigit(c)) {
                            // Testing for a letter but character is a number
                            Toast.makeText(OpenForm.this, R.string.badLetter + " " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        //return boxInput;
                    }
                }

                return boxInput;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In XML you can add this.

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

to get the text from it to validate you can do this..

```
String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();

if (text.equals("whatev") {

}
```

To limit the edit text programmatically....

```
InputFilter[] filter = new InputFilter[1];
filter[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10);
editText.setFilters(filter);
```

You can still get the text out of it like above.

Comment: This is the correct solution. Be aware that `android:maxLength="10"` has no function anymore if you call `et.setFilters` because it overwrites all filter set by xml. So if you set any filters programmatically, you must set them all programmatically.

Comment: I failed to mention that I am generating the edit text dynamically, so I can't use the XML version. I need to be able to handle this in code. (sorry).

Comment: `android:maxLength="10"` is equivalent to `InputFilter.LengthFilter`. So just set it with `et.setFilters();`

Comment: OK. I had seen that, but I am new to Java and with trying to combine validation on the InputFilter as well as the character limit, I didn't know how to apply both at the same time.